# dynamic option value not updating using IOptionsMonitor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

**Question:** I have a case where I need to save user token in the WebConfig section of appsettings.json using IOptionsMonitor.

**e.g.** When a user made a request to the app, request middleware will make request to another source of authentication check to validate the token and if the token is valid it will set the token back to WebConfig section of appsettings.json and from the view we are passing this token back to the view for other api calls that will be used for other system to authenticate user request.

**Problem:** Everything works fine until someone change the value of any property from appsettings.json WebConfig section or someone update the wwwroot folder for views supporting javascript files. Although it shows that it is updating the value but it always show null when we access from IOptionsMonitors DI instant.

this is the minimal code that I have

**program.cs**

```cs
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
             Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
             .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
             .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
             {
                 webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
             });
    }
```

**startup.cs**

```cs
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
           
            services.Configure<WebConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("WebConfig"));
            services.AddAuthentication();
            services.AddSession();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseSession();

            app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ClientMiddleware<WebConfig>));//used to  set dynamic properties from HttpContext i.e auth token

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            });
        }
    }
```

**ClientRequest.cs**

```cs
public class ClientMiddleware<WebConfigContext> where WebConfigContext : class, new()
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _requestDelegate;

        private readonly Models.CommonWebConfig appConfig;
        public ClientMiddleware(RequestDelegate requestDelegate, IOptionsMonitor<WebConfigContext> webConfig)
        {
            _requestDelegate = requestDelegate;
            appConfig = webConfig.CurrentValue as Models.CommonWebConfig;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            string AuthToken = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(context.User.Identity.Name) ? context.Request.Query["api_token"].ToString() : context.User.Identity.Name;


            this.appConfig.AuthToken = AuthToken;

            await _requestDelegate(context);
        }
    }
```

**View/Home/Index.cshtml**

```html
@{
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/application/react/dist/page.js"></script>
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```cs
@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsMonitor<TestApp.Models.Foundation.WebConfig> config
    
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        @Html.JsonConstantsScriptReact(config.CurrentValue, "Constants")
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
    </head>
    
    <!body>
        @RenderBody()
    </!body>
    </html>
```

**WebConfig.cs**

```cs
public class WebConfig
    {
        public string StaticProperty { get; set; }
        public string DynamicProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

**appsettings.json**

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "WebConfig": {
    "StaticProperty": "0006"
  }
}
```

Is it a good approach to handle this case if not what could be the better optimized solution?

Comment: _"I need to save user token"_ - why? access tokens, id_tokens and refresh_tokens are incredibly security-sensitive so persisting them to disk without proper safeguards is just a bad idea (especially in what I assume is a web-hosting account?) - besides, you shouldn't noeamlly save them anyway: in OIDC, for example, an `access_token ` usually expires within 5 minutes and a `refresh_token`  shouldn't exceed the life of an end-user's session (and as `id_token`s contain PII they shouldn't be saved at all anyway) - so... why?

Comment: First thing these token and this application reside in private network, second thing token in here are having atleast two days expiry and third saving token on runtime just to utilize them on frontend for a specific user as this application will use module based views for react application that will required user token to make other system calls for supporting data

Answer (score 0):

`IOptionsMonitor` is not meant to be used in the way you are describing (i.e change the content of appsettings.json) either `appsettings.json` is meant to be used to pass data from controller to view.

You might make use of `HttpContext.Items` for this scenario:

on your middleware you do the following change:

```
// this.appConfig.AuthToken = AuthToken; remove this

HttpContext.Items["authToken"] = AuthToken;
```

And then in your view/layout you can access it as following:

```
@{var authToken = Context.Items["authToken"] as string}
```

Comment: can you please add brief information why cannot we use this way? and IOptionsMonitor is right choice to use for appsettings? if not why

Comment: it is one of the ways to use appsettings and is used to receive a notification when appsettings in this case is changed. But you can't use it to change the content of appsettings.